# Is there a way to filter a text file using grep (or any other tool), so that you can get a section of the file that's encased in bracers or brackets?

Tags: regex, linux, lua, grep

I got several files that look something like this:

```
universe = {
    ["stars"] = {
        ["Sun"] = {
            ["planets"] = "9",
            ["life"] = "Yes",
            ["asteroid"] = "9001"
        },
        ["Alpha Centauri"] = {
            ["planets"] = "3",
            ["life"] = "No",
            ["asteroid"] = "20"
        },
        ["Rigel"] = {
            ["planets"] = "5",
            ["life"] = "No",
            ["asteroid"] = "11"
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to find, for instance, every block where ["life"] equals "No". I realize this could be handled better if it was within a database (or something with a structure), but I'm not sure how to convert this data onto that.

I have a bunch of files in this format, and I'd like to run a command that could display the sections (up to the immediate parent bracket) where the condition is true, so for the previous example, I'd like to get:

```
        ["Alpha Centauri"] = {
            ["planets"] = "3",
            ["life"] = "No",
            ["asteroid"] = "20"
        },
        ["Rigel"] = {
            ["planets"] = "5",
            ["life"] = "No",
            ["asteroid"] = "11"
        }
```

Can this be done with GREP? Or is there any other tool that could do something like this?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

Example 2: https://regex101.com/r/jO9dU5/1

Comment: This is a Data Structure. Which language product this DS ?

Comment: Well, I guess I meant something that could be queried. This is from a dump of data of a game (World of Warcraft), which uses LUA.

Comment: Why not using the proper `lua` code to retrieve the needed items ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I don't know of an interpreter that can do such, and this information is only "read" within the game. I'd have to create a script that could run within the game to export this information, which would be even harder than the approach via regexp.

Comment: Added an answer with a lua2perl parser

Comment: Where and how is this output going to be used? For example, are you looking to pipe this into another program or script for further processing? Do you just need the output printed to stdout? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible through grep which supports `-P` (*Perl Regex*) parameter.

```
$ grep -oPz '.*\[[^\[\]]*\]\s*=\s*\{[^{}]*\["life"\]\s*=\s*"No"[^{}]*}.*' file
        ["Alpha Centauri"] = {
            ["planets"] = "3",
            ["life"] = "No",
            ["asteroid"] = "20"
        },
        ["Rigel"] = {
            ["planets"] = "5",
            ["life"] = "No",
            ["asteroid"] = "11"
        }
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/44)

From `grep --help`

```
 -z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline
 -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
```

Update:

```
\[[^\n]*\]\h*=\h*\{(?!,\s*\[[^\[\]]*\]\h*=\h*{).*?\["fontSize"\]\h*=\h*20,.*?\}(?=,\s*\[[^\[\]]*\]\h*=\h*{|\s*})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jO9dU5/3)

```
$ pcregrep -oM '(?s)[^\n]*\[[^\n]*\]\h*=\h*\{(?!,\s*\[[^\[\]]*\]\h*=\h*{).*?\["fontSize"\]\h*=\h*20,.*?\}(?=,\s*\[[^\[\]]*\]\h*=\h*{|\s*})' file
    ["frame 1"] = {
        ["fontSize"] = 20,
        ["displayStacks"] = "%p",
        ["xOffset"] = 251.000518798828,
        ["stacksPoint"] = "BOTTOM",
        ["regionType"] = "icon",
        ["yOffset"] = 416.000183105469,
        ["anchorPoint"] = "CENTER",
        ["parent"] = "Target Shit",
        ["numTriggers"] = 1,
        ["customTextUpdate"] = "update",
        ["id"] = "Invulnerabilities 2",
        ["icon"] = true,
        ["fontFlags"] = "OUTLINE",
        ["stacksContainment"] = "OUTSIDE",
        ["zoom"] = 0,
        ["auto"] = true,
        ["selfPoint"] = "CENTER",
        ["width"] = 60,
        ["frameStrata"] = 1,
        ["desaturate"] = false,
        ["stickyDuration"] = true,
        ["font"] = "Emblem",
        ["inverse"] = false,
        ["height"] = 60,
    }
    ["frame 2"] = {
        ["fontSize"] = 20,
        ["displayStacks"] = "%p",
        ["parent"] = "Target Shit",
        ["xOffset"] = 118.000427246094,
        ["stacksPoint"] = "BOTTOM",
        ["anchorPoint"] = "CENTER",
        ["untrigger"] = {
        },
        ["regionType"] = "icon",
        ["color"] = {
            1, -- [1]
            1, -- [2]
            1, -- [3]
            1, -- [4]
        },
        ["desaturate"] = false,
        ["frameStrata"] = 1,
        ["stickyDuration"] = true,
        ["width"] = 60,
        ["font"] = "Emblem",
        ["inverse"] = false,
        ["icon"] = true,
        ["height"] = 60,
        ["yOffset"] = 241
    }
```

`(?s)` DOTALL modifier which makes dots in your regex to match even line breaks.

Comment: This works, I'm just running into a small complication. The files in question have 2 or even up to 4 more depth levels than I expressed in my example, so when I run this on them, only those with the 3 depth levels are matched, the rest aren't, even though the given pattern is supposed to be matched. Forgive, I know very little of regexp, could there be a way to retrieve those as well?

Comment: could you provide an example which replicate the above problem? Please provide it in your question.

Comment: I've tried to use this on my terminal, and it seems that `grep` doesn't match any new lines. I tried to use `pcregrep` and I get no results either. Matches work, but it doesn't seem to pickup previous (or following) lines, even if I use the `-M` parameter with pcregrep.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Lua program:

```
local function find(w,t,p)
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        if v==w then
            print(p.."."..k)
        elseif type(v)=="table" then
            find(w,v,p.."."..k)
        end
    end
end

find("No",universe,"universe")
```

Add the definition of `universe` before this code.

If you really want to do text processing, try this instead:

```
S=[[
universe = {
...
}
]]

for w in S:gmatch('%b[] = {[^{]-"No".-},?') do
    print(w)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using a proper [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) parser in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

This is not a quick'n'dirty snippet, but a robust way to query a lua's DS :

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Lua;                              # lua 2 perl parser
use Data::Dumper;                           # to dump Data Structures (in color)

# retrieving the lua'DS in a perl's DS
my $root = Data::Lua->parse_file('lua.conf');

# iterating over keys of planet's HASH
foreach my $planet (keys $root->{universe}->{stars}) {
    print Dumper { $planet => $root->{universe}->{stars}->{$planet} }
        if $root->{universe}->{stars}->{$planet}->{life} eq "No";
}
```

### Output

```
$VAR1 = {
     'Rigel' => {
            'planets' => '5',
            'life' => 'No',
            'asteroid' => '11'
           }
    };
$VAR1 = {
     'Alpha Centauri' => {
                'asteroid' => '20',
                'life' => 'No',
                'planets' => '3'
               }
    };
```

### How To

- install `Data::Lua` if not already installed with `# cpan Data::Lua`
- put the Data Structure in the file `lua.conf`
- put this script in the same dir in by example `lua_DS_parser.pl`
- run the script with `$ perl lua_DS_parser.pl`
- enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this
    grep -C 2 -E 'life.+= "No"' path_to_file

But in my opinion better way is converting files to some common format.